# HighCharts & MVC: How to load whole graph definition and data with JSON?

Tags: json, model-view-controller, dynamic, highcharts, jsonresult

I'd like to know how it is possible to load options & data graph or whole graph structure returning a JSON object?

In particular, I'd like to dynamically create **options**, **categories**, axis, data, etc. with JSON; I think it is possible, but I only found informations describing how to load data& series, not options.

For example, I'd like to define title, xAxis, etc, returning a JSon Object:

```
 [...]

  title: {
     text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
  },
  xAxis: {
     categories: []
  }, 

 [...]
```

In particular, I need to dynamically create a more complex graph, similar to this one: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was thinking...is it possible to use ViewBag to build up parts of the javascripts??? Is it a so bad idea? THX

Comment: I think you can simply create a route/page that creates an object (containing the same properties as the chart would, title, subtile) and the use System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer to serialize and output the chart. On the consumer page you can use jquery to make an ajax call to the REST service and then inizialize the chart with the data returned. I'm doing the same thing right now (in PHP however).

Comment: Thank you @Gremo! May you give me some example of this solution, if possible? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) is possible to create the chart on the server side as you like without using JavaScript or JSON. Here is the example which you would like do with the library:

```
Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
.InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column })
.SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender" })
.SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = new[] { "Apples", "Oranges", "Pears", "Grapes", "Bananas" } })
.SetYAxis(new YAxis
            {
                AllowDecimals = false,
                Min = 0,
                Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Number of fruits" }
            })
.SetTooltip(new Tooltip { Formatter = "TooltipFormatter" })
.SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions { Column = new PlotOptionsColumn { Stacking = Stackings.Normal } })
.SetSeries(new[]
            {
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "John",
                    Data = new Data(new object[] { 5, 3, 4, 7, 2 }),
                    Stack = "male"
                },
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "Joe",
                    Data = new Data(new object[] { 3, 4, 4, 2, 5 }),
                    Stack = "male"
                },
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "Jane",
                    Data = new Data(new object[] { 2, 5, 6, 2, 1 }),
                    Stack = "female"
                },
                new Series
                {
                    Name = "Janet",
                    Data = new Data(new object[] { 3, 0, 4, 4, 3 }),
                    Stack = "female"
                }
            });
```

You can find a lot of ASP.NET MVC examples here: http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/releases/view/80650